# Excel: How to Sum/Aggregate results of "Filter" Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table.

[image]

When I am using formula:

```
=FILTER(A1:C7,B1:B7="red",)
```

what I am getting is:

[image]

What I would like to get however is:

[image]

Any ideas how to do it?

Note: Using the `Filter` function is a must.

Comment: I would look at unique() for column A then "red".

Comment: why not use a pivot table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, FILTER(A2:C7,B2:B7="red"),
     φ, INDEX(α,,1)&"|"&INDEX(α,,2),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(φ,"|"),TEXTAFTER(φ,"|"),
     MMULT(N(φ=TOROW(φ)),DROP(α,,2)))))
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd> applicable to `Beta Users`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, FILTER(A2:C7,B2:B7="red"),
     PIVOTBY(TAKE(α,,2),,TAKE(α,,-1),SUM,,0))
```

---

Or Using <kbd>GROUPBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, FILTER(A2:C7,INDEX(A2:C7,,2)="red"), GROUPBY(TAKE(α,,2),TAKE(α,,-1),SUM,,0))
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=PIVOTBY(A2:B7,,C2:C7,SUM,,0,,,,B2:B7="red")
```

---

Alternative version of <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> realized it would perform more efficiently & better than the earlier version.

[image]

---

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(A2:B7,MMULT((A2:A7=TOROW(A2:A7))*(B2:B7="red"),C2:C7)),B2:B7="red"))
```

---

Comment: I am not a Beta User. So ```GROUPBY()``` or ```PIVOTBY()``` are not available to me.
But the very first option worked for me. Thank you!
I hope ```GROUPBY()``` or ```PIVOTBY()``` are released to official version asap.

Comment: The `MMULT()` should work, also I have just posted that as an alternative, I have found there are some issues with those functions for now, should nt be used as it is in `Beta` testing. shared as a knowledge purpose. Yes usually all new functions are released by batches as far I have learnt from experts! And not just that in workplace `Beta` will not be allowed to be enabled, usually unless there is a special grant for the same!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Mayukh Bhattacharya's answer, but without text manipulation.

```
=LET(
    valid_range, FILTER(A2:C7, B2:B7="red"),
    values, MMULT(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(valid_range,,1) = TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(INDEX(valid_range,,1))))*1, 
INDEX(valid_range,,3)),
    HSTACK(UNIQUE(DROP(valid_range,,-1)), values))
```

Answer (score 2):

If applicable, use [GROUPBY()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/groupby-function-5e08ae8c-6800-4b72-b623-c41773611505):

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=GROUPBY(A2:B7,C2:C7,SUM,,0,,B2:B7="red")
```

You say using `FILTER()` is a must, however we have now used the internal groupby-filter which seems fine to me.

---

Alternatively, "old"-fashioned:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(A2:B7,SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,A2:A7,B2:B7,"red")),B2:B7="red"))
```

Comment: ```GROUPBY()```  is a function for BETA users only. Many still don't have access to BETA (especially if it's a corporate Excel).

Comment: @Elmar, absolutely, however you have many alternatives. Anyway; I have also edited in an alternative using old-fashioned `SUMIFS()`.

Answer (score 1):

For those having access to Beta version of Excel:

`=LET(f,FILTER(A2:C7,B2:B7="red"),PIVOTBY(TAKE(f,,2),,DROP(f,,2),SUM,,0))`

or
`=LET(f,FILTER(A2:C7,B2:B7="red"),GROUPBY(TAKE(f,,2),DROP(f,,2),SUM,,0))`
or
`=LET(g,GROUPBY(A2:B7,C2:C7,SUM,,0),FILTER(g,INDEX(g,,2)="red"))`

[image]